# How can you find out which extensions a twitch streamer is using?

Tags: twitch, twitch-api

How can you check which extensions a twitch streamer is using?

For example, extensions used when

- creating their 'About' page, or
- when running custom codes (e.g. `!event`) during a stream

Answer (score 1):

You can see the extensions active on a streamers page via the "Get User Active Extensions" API endpoint. Currently this involves a call to `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/extensions` with a `user_id` query string parameter

The current documentation for the endpoint is at https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-user-active-extensions

As for "custom codes" you are out of luck, since there is no easy way to get what channel bot is in use and the commands that channel bot has. Since it will vary by channel and bot in use.

Comment: I get a `{"error":"Unauthorized","status":401,"message":"OAuth token is missing"}`, I will try after setting up OAuth and report back (once I have a token). Thanks again!

Comment: Yes all of Helix requires a token. This endpoints supports any kind of token.